# Button JS functions ignored/ sent to Php_Action

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently running my website using a local server via apache. On my website, when the "login" button is clicked, a popup screen expands with two buttons (one to login using google, one using facebook). I've so far attempted to write JS functions that are called when the google button is clicked. However, when I click it now, it directs me to a new page with the message "The requested URL /action_page.php was not found on this server."

I think it has to do with the messy organization of my html page:

```
  <html>
<head>
  <title>Columbia Ride Share</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
  <header> 
       <h1 class = "page-title">Columbia Ride Share</h1>
       <nav>
           <ul>
               <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
               <li><a href="">create a ride</a></li>
               <li class = "login">
                   <button onclick = "document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">Login</button>
               </li>
               <div id="id01" class="modal">
                   <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                       <div class="imgcontainer">
                           <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                            </div>
                           <div class="loginMsg">
                               <p>hi there!</p>
                               <p>log in to post and comment on columbia ride share</p>
                           </div> 
                           <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">connect with facebook</button>
               <button onclick = "googleSignin()" class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">connect with google     </button>
                    </form>
               </div>

           </ul>
       </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class = "JFK">
            <h6>JFK</h6>
               <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                   <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "JFK">
           <h6>NEWARK</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class = "bottomRow">
           <h6>LAGUARDIA</h6>
                <p> <a href = "ridesToJFK.html">to</a>
                <a href = "#">from</a></p>
        </div>
           <div class = "bottomRow">
              <button class = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('id02').style.display='block'"style="width:auto;">CREATE A RIDE</button>
           </div>    
               <div id="id02" class="modal">
              <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
              <div class="imgcontainer">
                           <span onclick="document.getElementById('id02').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                      </div>
              <div class = "loginMsg">
                      <p>Where are you headed?<p>
                          <a href="create-a-ride.html">I need a ride to the airport</a>
                          <a href="create-a-ride.html">I need a ride to campus</a>
                      </div>
           </form>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.8/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAIY9XOb5QVDTxJKxtvSZRiyqgpGasHF3M",
    authDomain: "columbia-ride-share.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://columbia-ride-share.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "columbia-ride-share.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "1058399238109"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<script src = "app.js"></script>
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<script> 
var modal = document.getElementById('id02');

window.onclick= function(event){

    if(event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Highlights version:

```
<div id="id01" class="modal">
                   <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
                       <div class="imgcontainer">
                           <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                            </div>
                           <div class="loginMsg">
                               <p>hi there!</p>
                               <p>log in to post and comment on columbia ride share</p>
                           </div> 
                           <button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">connect with facebook</button>
               <button onclick = "googleSignin()" class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">connect with google     </button>
                    </form>
               </div>
```

This is my app.js:

```
 function googleSignin(){
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
        console.log('bitch ok');
    }

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
    // ...
        }
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        }).catch(function(error) {
       // Handle Errors here.
           var errorCode = error.code;
           var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
           var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
           var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
       });
```

What can I change so that it fires off the googleSignIn function rather than look for a action_page.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely what is going on - you are using a `<form>` element, and the default action when you click a button in the form is to submit the page, which you have set up as `action_page.php`.  You should be able to adjust your click handler for the button with `event.preventDefault();` to disable that default action on your page, and instead make the javascript function handle the click.

If you can post your code to a jsfiddle page, further testing can be provided.

Comment: SO wont allow me to share the jsfiddle page, is there another way to lend people my code in a testing environment?

Comment: yes! by simply putting event.preventDefault() in the first line of my googleSignIn function - it works properly!